# Negative values are not being shown at the axes in DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling, axeslabel

I used `DensityPlot` for the function $x^2+y^2$  (or any other more complicated function) for $x$ and $y$ values
`{x,-2,2}`,`{y,-2,2}`, but in the resulting plot, the negative $x$ and $y$ values are not shown at the axes. (They are marked 2,1,0,1,2 for both axes.) Any help?

Comment: You need to show us your **exact** code, including any style changes you may have made.

Answer (score 1):

MMA version 14 Windows 10.

```
DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]